# how to get gps data without permission reguesting in android8.0 above?

Tags: android

I 'm developing a certain app.
I 'm trying to get GPS data in samsung galaxy s8 - android 8.0.
App runs in foreground service, but it doesn't works well.

It returns error string like below.
java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

Permissions in Android Manifest file:
"uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" "
"uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" "

Is there any way to get gps location without runtime permission request?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to acquire permissions without asking at the run time. However, from API 22 and lower, all the permissions are automatically granted at install time.